# Git pull/push error from smartgit

Tags: git, github

I'm getting the same error message. How did you solve it?

```
Malformed value for push.default: simple 
Must be one of nothing, matching, tracking or current. 
bad config file line 8 in C:\users\sabs/.gitconfig
```

I had a Git version of 1.8.x. Later I changed it to 1.7.9 for Jenkins build purpose.

Now I'm facing this issue. Any pointers on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `simple` value for `push.default` was added in git 1.7.11.  See https://coderwall.com/p/dnofpw

I would suggest changing that to be either `tracking` or `current`.  I'm sure someone else will give you specific reasons for either, and which is better than the other.